# C# connect, But java does'nt connect

Tags: java, c#, api

I'm tring to connect "https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/?pair=btc_thb"
this url is working on chrome, postman.
I can connect this url with C#.
But ca'nt connect with java.

```cs
namespace Exchanges.Satang
{
    class SatangApi
    {
        private static class WebApi
        {
            private static readonly HttpClient st_client = new HttpClient();

            static WebApi()
            {
                st_client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            }

            public static HttpClient Client { get { return st_client; } }

            public static string Query(string url)
            {
                var resultString = Client.GetStringAsync(url).Result;
                return resultString;
            }
        }
        public static string GetOrders(string symbol)
        {
            const string queryStr = "https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/?pair=";
            var response = WebApi.Query(queryStr + symbol);
            return response.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

this C# code working well
but following java code not working, get 403 error.

```java
    private String publicOperation(String operation) throws IOException, BadResponseException {

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(baseUrl+operation);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/?pair=btc_thb
        int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();

        if(responseCode!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            throw new BadResponseException(responseCode);
        }
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
        return result.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some servers expect a `User-Agent` header to be present in the request to consider it as a valid request. So you need to add that to your request as follows.

```
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "My-User-Agent");
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

The value of this header (`My-User-Agent` in the above example) can be set to any String you desire for this endpoint. For example, Postman sets something like `PostmanRuntime/7.16.3` for this.

C# might be doing this internally, so you didn't have to set it explicitly.

Comment: @Josh 404 is a server response. It is used to indicate that the requested resource doesn't exist. You shouldn't unaccept Udith's answer because that is a) outside of the scope of this question, and b) given your provided code Udith has no way of knowing that the URL is different since it isn't supplied in the Java example.

Comment: https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/?pair=btc_thb   please check this url. I can access this url on chrome. And I can access this url with C#. But java ca'nt connect. Please help me.

Comment: Then first hardcode the URL in your code and see if it works. I checked and it worked for me from Java.
`URL url = new URL("https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/?pair=btc_thb");`

Comment: Thanks very much. You are great java developer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getOrders(SatangCurrencyPairs currencyPair) throws IOException, BadResponseException {

    String operation="orders/?pair="+currencyPair.toString();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl+operation);
    //URL url_ = new URL("https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/?pair=btc_thb");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "java client");
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/?pair=btc_thb
    int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();

    if(responseCode!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        throw new BadResponseException(responseCode);
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: You should probably improve your answer with a brief description of your solution, IMHO.